# onTouch calling invalidate onDraw - not smooth

Tags: java, android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, ondraw

I have a code in my custom view, where if I touch, a circle is drawn. When I move the circle follow along. Code as below

```
// override onDraw
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (circleBounds != null) {
        canvas.drawArc(circleBounds, 360, 360, false, mPaint);
    }
}

// when ACTION_DOWN start touch according to the x,y values
private void startTouch(float x, float y) {
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
    circleBounds.set(mX - mRadius, mY - mRadius, mX + mRadius, mY + mRadius);

    invalidate();
}


//override the onTouchEvent
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        startTouch(x, y);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        startTouch(x, y);
        break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

When I move slowly, the movement is smooth. But when I move fast, one could feel the flickering. I guess invalidate() happens many time, causing the flickering. Is there a way to make it smoother (reduce the flickering on the drawn circle)?

Comment: What's the goal of you?You may use other way to achieve it.

Comment: I just like to when I touch, the circle follow my hand wherever I move. It did achieve what I wanted to do. But just feel it is not as smooth (slight flickering). What are other ways to achieve it?

Comment: remove `mPath.moveTo(x, y);` as you dont use `mPath` anywhere

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invalidate is not your issue, the system has double buffering, and you should not see a flicker.
From your code, I can think of 2 way to improve:

1. in onStartTouch you call mPath.moveTo(). It is not clear why you need mPath, but this path will keep growing and growing and will need more memory
2. canvas.drawArc is rendered by by CPU (it creates a bitmap and draws the arc into it on every call to onDraw). It would be faster to render yourself the circle once into a bitmap, and draw that bitmap in onDraw. If you keep using the same bitmap, it will be loaded once to the GPU and drawing will be much faster

Comment: Thanks for the input. Ya, the mPath is not being used should be removed. Render to bitmap is a good idea, especially for complex drawing. I made the change but it is still not very smooth, similar to drawArc slight flickering. But I guess, I'm a little too picky on the minor flickering. For sure a more complex drawing, bitmap and manual draw will have distinct differences. I'm ticking your answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but in case someone else has same problem, the solution is to use `postInvalidate()` instead of the `invalidate()` in the `onTouchEvent` method, which will make it much more fluid.

As we receive many events in `onTouchEvent`, it's more effective to put invalidate call into events queue for future processing instead of doing it immediately.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class MyView extend FrameLayout implement OnTouchListener{
   public MyView(params){
      init();
   }

   private void init(){
      ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
      imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.logo);
      addView(imageview)

      imageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
   }

   private boolean onTouch(params){
       //some logic to control
       //use imageView.setLayoutParams() instead of invalidate();
   }
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... Doesn't seem to related to my question above. I'm creating custom view, that could be used by any activity/fragment. I'm not creating an activity or layout.